# Angular - Is there a in-build way to loop a object and update the values?

Tags: angularjs

I have a object, which contains the various numbers in the `object.Value`. I would like to loop through and update the `object.Value` in to `2 decimal` numbers.. what is the correct and angular way to do this?

here is my array:

```
$scope.calendar = [{"ContractMonths":[{"ContractDays":[{"Value":30},{"Value":25},{"Value":4}],"Value":8},{"ContractDays":[{"Value":5}],"Value":7},{"ContractDays":[{"Value":14}],"Value":5}],"Value":2015},{"ContractMonths":[{"ContractDays":[{"Value":15}],"Value":1}],"Value":2014},{"ContractMonths":[{"ContractDays":[{"Value":21}],"Value":3}],"Value":2012}]
```

the result i am lookin for is :

```
$scope.calendar = [{"ContractMonths":[{"ContractDays":[{"Value":30},{"Value":25},{"Value":04}],"Value":8},{"ContractDays":[{"Value":05}],"Value":07},{"ContractDays":[{"Value":14}],"Value":05}],"Value":2015},{"ContractMonths":[{"ContractDays":[{"Value":15}],"Value":01}],"Value":2014},{"ContractMonths":[{"ContractDays":[{"Value":21}],"Value":03}],"Value":2012}]
```

some valid reasons, i don't want to use the `filters`

Any one help me. ( this is simply updating the single digit number to adding `0` to make in to 2 decimal)

Comment: JS supports Number which in case is zero decimals, *treats it as* an integer. Appart from formatting, if they're integers, it won't make sense.

From this, why don't you want to use filters?

Comment: I am not able to get you. ok for display purpose how can i make this in to 2 decimals even using filter.

Answer (score 0):

JS which is not a stronly typed language supports `Number` class, which in case it's dealings zero decimals, *treats any number as* an integer.

If *they're floats*, they will get these decimals, otherwise they *won't*. Well, you might concern for decimal precision and stuff but we know this is not the case now.

Appart from formatting, if they're integers, it won't make sense to use something like **lodash** to loop over your object and nested arrays to do something to values.

**Use filters**

A first example:

So, lets say you want to show a `Number` `value` in decimal format:

```
{{value | number:2}}
```

So, for your case, let's assume your module's name is `numbersApp` and you will define `numbersFormatFilter` custom filter:

```
angular.module('numbersApp').filter('numbersFormatFilter', [function(){
  return function (number) {
    return String(number).match(/\d/g).length === 1 ? return "0" + number : String(number);
}]);
```

Then you could have at your HTML:

```
{{value | numbersFormatFilter}}
```

Comment: It prints the number 4 as '4.00', i am looking for '04' in case if the digit are less than 10

Comment: So you're not exactly talking about decimals, it's pure displaying stuff. You can use a custom filter, let me update my answer

Comment: only one. less than 10

Comment: So for 45 it should be 045, for 1000 it should be 01000?

Comment: No 45 should be 45. only. if 4 then 04. (less than 10's only need to added a 0 )